# Correct word for sherbet in French

Tags: anglais, usage

I'm working on learning French and looked up the word for sherbet. Google said sorbet. In English, sorbet(frozen fruit and sugar) is completely different than sherbet (frozen fruit and milk / dairy). [Food network explanation](https://www.foodnetwork.com/how-to/packages/food-network-essentials/sherbet-vs-sorbet)

Talking to a few friends that are fluent in French was unhelpful as they were unfamiliar with what sherbet is. Googling around was unhelpful as the internet gave examples that they mean they same thing, (when they absolutely do not) or why English often pronounces it sherbert in English when there's no R in the word.

I turn to you wise members of French Stack Exchange and hope you can clarify whether Google is confused, English is doing weird things again when taking words from other languages, or French really does use sorbet to refer to both foods.

Comment: Have you tried an English-French dictionary? Sherbet is mostly not a thing in Europe but you will still find explicit translations with a very small amount of research.

Comment: 1-  Your link doesn't work - at least on my computer, here's [Sherbet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherbet_(frozen_dessert)) on Wikipedia (no French page), the French page of [wiktionary](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/sherbet#en) gives sherbet, no translation just an explanation of what it is. I could find only one recipe for sherbet in French (commercial website). "Sherbet" is "sherbet" in French, it is a US import, like "cheesecake" (we call it cheesecake).

Comment: 2 -As far as I know "sherbert" is just an [alternative spelling](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sherbert) in the US, but it is the same product, but that could be a question for [seasoned advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/9379/what-is-the-difference-between-sorbet-and-sherbet/9381#9381). In Britain we used to have [sherbet](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/sherbet) (no "r") which is a totally different product. Indeed, most dictionaries translate "sherbet" as *sorbet* which is incorrect since *sorbet* contains no diary product whereas sherbet does.

Comment: @None the translation is good for most intents and purposes. Just because it is slightly different in one culture doesn't mean we shouldn't liken it to the closest thing in the other culture.

Comment: @guillaume31 Sorry I'm not sure I understand what you mean. If you mean *sorbet* is a good French translation for sherbet, then I don't agree (as a cook addict!), sorbet is the same thing in France in the US or in Britain: there's **no milk product**. In sherbet you have a dairy product (so not suitable for veggies). But I might not have understood what you meant, sorry.

Comment: @None the closest thing to "sherbet" is "sorbet" in French. If you want receivers to understand what you mean at all, it is often good enough to use a very close thing from their culture. Getting the message across beats precision most of the time. There are tons of examples of this in the culinary field.

Comment: [Sorbet lacté](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=%22sorbet+lact%C3%A9%22)" is an oxymoron, but It can be found in many French recipes.

Comment: Well according to my Visual French English Bilingual Dictionary I forgot I had, it too has sherbet being translated to sorbet; which leads me back to my original issue. In English, sorbet and sherbet refer to completely different foods. Everything I've found so far says French uses the same word for both foods, which would lead to misunderstandings and be "wrong". 

 @None 's answer of "There is no word, just use the English word", is fine. I was trying to verify / dig deeper to make sure I wasn't misunderstanding something since Google and other websites are seemingly mistranslating it.

Comment: @Nick: look at the [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/sherbet) entry for *sherbet*. The definition is *(États-Unis) Sorbet comprenant un peu de lait.* and it has a "Note": *Aux États-Unis, le sherbet contient un peu de lait tandis que le sorbet n’en contient pas.* If you really want to distinguish *sherbet* and *sorbet* in French, you could use *sorbet lacté* and *sorbet sans lait*.

Comment: @guillaume31 I don't think you get the message across if you use the word "sorbet"  (supposed to contain no milk product) for some food that  contains milk. As Graffito says, adding lacté gives the correct information.

Comment: @None if you're an ice cream shop employee trying to explain what you sell, maybe :) In most other cases, "sorbet" is perfectly good enough.

Comment: @guillaume31 What about vegans? Moreover [French legislation](https://www.economie.gouv.fr/dgccrf/Publications/Vie-pratique/Fiches-pratiques/Glaces-cremes-glacees-sorbets) states that *sorbets* mustn't contain milk or fat, so even *sorbet lacté/laitier* would not comply to French food law.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

D'après l'[office québécois de la langue française](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/fiche-gdt/fiche/8351942/sorbet-laitier), cela s'appellerait un **sorbet laitier** au Québec et n'aurait pas d'équivalent en français européen.

Parlant le français de France et n'ayant jamais entendu ce terme moi-même auparavant, je pense qu'il est cependant tout à fait compréhensible comme un dessert à mi-chemin entre le sorbet et la crème glacée, et serait donc ma recommendation même en dehors du Québec.

Comment: +1 Par contre, pour ceux qui ne cliqueraient pas sur le lien, peut-être pourrais-tu insérer dans ta réponse ce qui explique pourquoi en Europe on n'utilise  pas le terme de "sorbet laitier" (ou lacté comme suggéré dans des commentaires) : « Selon les législations française et européenne, un sorbet ne contient pas d'œufs, ni de matières grasses ou d'ingrédients lactés. »

Comment: Ce point sur la réglementation n'a pas l'air d'être vrai selon https://www.economie.gouv.fr/dgccrf/Publications/Vie-pratique/Fiches-pratiques/Glaces-cremes-glacees-sorbets : "l’utilisation de protéines laitières est compatible avec la dénomination « sorbet ». En effet, l’emploi de protéines laitières est admis à très faible dose (moins de 1 %), à des fins technologiques, pour améliorer l'onctuosité du produit fini."

Answer (score 6):

Il n'y a pas de mot en français pour **sherbet**. Les produits glacés les plus courants sont la **crème glacée**, à base de crème fraîche, et le **sorbet**, à base d'eau. Les deux sont regroupés dans le terme plus général **glace**.

Les deux possibilités sont d'utiliser le mot **sherbet** ou de faire une périphrase explicative **un sorbet avec un peu de lait**.

Dans un texte un peu long, on peut commencer par introduire le terme et sa définition, puis continuer avec le terme seul.

Comment: Le terme crème glacée est quand même assez peu utilisé (en France en tout cas). Dans la langage courant, on oppose le sorbet et glace (ex sorbet à la fraise et glace à la vanille), même si effectivement glace est aussi utilisé de façon générique (sorbet + glace).

Comment: There's a similar problem in Italian. What's the Italian word for "gelato" (which in Italian means "ice cream")?